# Any way to move an existing local git pre-push hook written in ruby to run a bitbucket server?

Tags: git, bitbucket, githooks, bitbucket-server

As the title says, I have an existing local hook that is written in ruby. I'd like to move this hook server side. I've had a look through the bitbucket addons but didn't see anything that would allow me to run the ruby script.

Is there some way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

A hook runs in whatever language [its shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) instructs it to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

See for instance "[Slaying dragons with git, bash, and ruby](https://glenngillen.com/thoughts/slaying-dragons-git-bash-ruby)".

The only issue here is that a pre-push hook is a [client-side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), not a server-side: you can [declare hooks in a BitBucket server](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-repository-hooks-776639836.html), but none would be a pre-push one.
The article "[How to create a simple hook in Bitbucket Server](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/how-to-create-a-simple-hook-in-bitbucket-server-779171711.html)" do mention the `hooks` folder in its bare repos it is managing, so you can try and put it there, but I doubt it would be triggered.

Comment: You should be able to translate a pre-push hook into a pre-receive hook, though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The hook works fine client side. I currently have a server-side pre-receive hook to check commit messages, and I was hoping there would be an easy way to run the pre-push hook in a similar way.